# pattern that match a maware on a javascript file

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching, pcre

i need a regex to find a maware on infecteds sites.
The common js libs starts like:

```
(function(e){v...
```

or

```
/**
 * Some description
```

i need a regex that match everything before this sintaxe example: "Maware code"

```
var hglgfdrr4634hezfdg = 1; var d=document;var s=d.createElement('script'); s.type='text/javascript'; s.async=true;
var pl = String.from...}
/**
 * Some real description of the lib
```

-> Gist link: https://gist.github.com/mesaque/22cdee6ed131d7338af929579f18a297

Or another example:

```
var hglgfdrr4634hezfdg = 1; var d=document;var s=d.createElement('script'); s.type='text/javascript'; s.async=true;
var pl = String.from...}(function(e){var true code ahead..
```

-> Gist link: https://gist.github.com/mesaque/013c8c96ebc0c6e7a32189dad4e13420

i have tried this pattern `/^[^\/\*]*$/` but it is not working

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's a maware? I'm not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I think he wants to detect `malware` (wrong typing).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a regex that can match all text before a certain pattern occurs, but without selecting that pattern, you would use a positive lookahead

`/match(?=element)/`

Or in this case probably

`/[\s\S]+(?=var hglgfdrr4634hezfdg)/g`

I don't know if I fully understand what you're asking because it sounds like you want to select everything that comes before "var hglgfdrr4634hezfdg = 1; var d=document;var s=d.createElement('script');..." but then in the shared gists that code is at the very top, so I'm guessing those are samples taken from a larger file?